# Send array data from v-for loop into a prop (VUE)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, prop

How am I able to send some array data from v-for loop into a prop? So i can read it out inside de template.

**Example (index.html):**

```
<grid v-for="boss in bossesArray.slice(0, 20)" test="{{ boss.id }}"></grid>
```

Where the test="" is the prop inside the template.

**Template example (Grid.vue):**

```
<template>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__body">
      {{ test }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['test'],
    data: function () {
      return {
        msg: "This is a message",
        counter: 0
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**The result i get back is (Browser):**

```
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
{{ boss.id }}
```

Is there a way to send the boss id through the prop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass dynamic props like this

```
<grid v-for="boss in bossesArray.slice(0, 20)" v-bind:test="boss.id"></grid>
```

And short hand is:

```
<grid v-for="boss in bossesArray.slice(0, 20)" :test="boss.id"></grid>
```

You are passing prop using `test="{{boss.id}}"` which is passed as a static prop as you are not binding it and the value you passed to the static prop is considered a string which is `{{boss.id}}`